# Recursively Remove SVN files

Tags: find, rm, subversion

I'm still learning the bash shell.

I want to recursively find and remove svn files within the child directories of a given folder. I made the mistake of checking out instead of just cloning, so I'm trying to clean up my mess.

I've tried this, but I only get output of all the files found:

`rm | find -name ".svn"`

When I run this, I get no output and the files are still there:
`find . -executable -o ! -regex '.*\.svn' -exec rm -i {} \+`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easier method would be to *export* the revision you want instead of checking it out.  Try `svn help export` at the bash shell.

If you really want to use `find` to go through and remove all child directories called `.svn` you would do this:

`find /path/to/search -type d -iname .svn -print0 | xargs -0 rm`

EDIT

- `-type d` #look for directories only
- `-iname .svn`  #case insensitive matching, probably not necessary
- `-print0` #prints the full file name followed by a null character instead of newlines.  it allows file names with spaces or other whitespace to be passed properly to `xargs -0`

Comment: Yeah i made the mistake of not exporting so i'm trying to clean up my mess. I'll give that a try. Could you break down what you did in the command?

Comment: Glad to help out! :)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `rm -r`?  Plain old `rm` won't remove directories.  Also, I'd recommend the `-prune` switch to `find` here: `rm -r` already deletes all subdirectories, so there's no need to traverse them.

Comment: find . -type d -iname .svn -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf

Answer (score 3):

```
shopt -s globstar
rm -r **/.svn
```

Answer (score 2):

Most versions of `find` have a delete action:

```
$ find /path/in/question -type d -name .svn -delete
```

Make sure you run it without the delete and look over the results first!